# If $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+1}=1$ Show that $abc\le \frac{1}{8}$

Tags: inequality, jensen-inequality

Given positive reals $a,b$ and $c$, such that  $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+1}=1$$ Show that $$abc\le \frac{1}{8}$$

This problem is fairly easy we can just clear denominators and then use AM-GM. But since I want to get better at using Jensen's Inequality. I tried to use it here,

Note that $$ \sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a}}=1$$
Let $x=1/a, y=1/b$ and $c=1/z$. Then consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x} \quad x>0$$
$f$ is convex and by Jensen we have $$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+e^x}\ge \frac{1}{1+e^{x+y+z/3}}$$
Substuting $x\to \log x$ we get $$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{1}{3}\ge \frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{xyz}}$$
Hence $$xyz\ge 8\implies abc\le \frac{1}{8}.$$

Correct? I'm afraid of the substitutions that I used.

Edit:

@MartinR pointed out that the substitution $x\to \log x$ isn't correct since $f$ is convex for $x>0$ but $\log x$ can be negative. How can we fix this?

Comment: see this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294748/if-a-over-a1-b-over-b1-c-over-c1-1-prove-abc-le-1-8/2294768#2294768

Comment: @AlexeyKubanov The OP is familiar with the approaches in your linked question - they specifically want to use Jensen's inequality and not AM-GM.

Comment: I do not understand the notation $\sum_cyc$. I have never seen that before.

Comment: @projectilemotion oops.. my bad :( should I delete my comment?

Comment: @AlexeyKubanov No problem - in my opinion leaving the link there is fine, it might be useful for other readers who want to do it the standard way.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan It's a [cyclic sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum). For instance, the first equation means a sum over all cyclic permutations of $(a,b,c)$, i.e.
$$\frac{a}{a+1}+\frac{b}{b+1}+\frac{c}{c+1}=1\, .$$

Comment: Thank you. I should have looked at the related questions. But what is the interest of using a cyclic sum when the quantity to be added is a function of a single variable?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Just a notation - shorthand

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ is convex only for $x \ge 0$, but you use the convexity condition with $\log(a), \log(b), \log(c)$, which can be negative.

Comment: I knew something was off with my subs. Any idea how to fix this? @MartinR

Comment: There is an extension of Jensen's inequality to “half convex functions” (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1029-242X-2011-101), but I am not sure if that would help here.

Comment: This is kind of cheating, but you can prove AM-GM using Jensen's inequality and then apply the proof in the linked answer.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer Then you haven't learned anything new.

Comment: @PNT Well, who knows, you may get some new insights along the way, but anyways, as I said, it is kind of cheating.